# !curl commands in Python notebook fail with 500 Internal error

Tags: python, curl, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I am running the below code in Google Colab and get `The server encountered an internal error  or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request`. If I am running the command without passing in the variable `$data` like below, it runs perfectly fine. Only when I'm looping through the file and passing variables it seems to be failing

```
import csv
import json

reader = csv.reader(open('/content/drive/MyDrive/file5.csv'))
for row in reader:
    data = {"snps": row[0], "pop": "YRI", "r2_threshold": "0.9", "maf_threshold": "0.01"}
    data = json.dumps(data)
    data = "'{}'".format(data)
    !curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "$data" 'https://ldlink.nci.nih.gov/LDlinkRest/snpclip?token=e3e559472899'
```

This works:

```
!curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"snps": "rs3\nrs4", "pop":"YRI", "r2_threshold": "0.1", "maf_threshold": "0.01"}' 'https://ldlink.nci.nih.gov/LDlinkRest/snpclip?token=e3e559472899'
```

Comment: First of all use request as it will be easy to manage its properties. Also try printing out the values which you are passing to the request, so that you will come to know in which line the error is occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Actually, `ipython` does allow you to run `!` escapes in a loop; the actual error in your code is purely in the incorrect quoting (especially the addition of single quotes around the `data` value, but there could be more).

Original (partially incorrect) answer below.

---

The `!` escape tells your notebook (Google Colab, Jupyter, or what have you; basically whatever is running `ipython` as a kernel or similar) to leave Python and run a shell command. Python itself has no support for this; the closest approximation would be something like

```
import subprocess
...
for row in reader:
    data = {"snps": row[0], "pop": "YRI", "r2_threshold": "0.9", "maf_threshold": "0.01"}
    data = json.dumps(data)
    # This was wrong on so many levels
    # data = "'{}'".format(data)
    subprocess.run(['curl', '-k',
        '-H', "Content-Type: application/json",
        '-X', 'POST', '-d', data,
        'https://ldlink.nci.nih.gov/LDlinkRest/snpclip?token=e3e559472899'],
        text=True, check=True)
```

though avoiding `subprocess` and running Python [`urllib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html) or [`requests`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) code to perform the `POST` would be more efficient and elegant, and give you more control over what gets sent and how it gets handled.

How to properly quote strings when translating between shell commands and Python requires you to understand the shell's quoting behavior. I'll just briefly note that I left double quotes where they were not incorrect in your original command, but otherwise preferred single quotes, and of course, `data` now refers to a proper Python variable with that name, not a shell variable with the same name.

To reiterate: `ipython` (which is what your notebook is an interface to) knows how to run both Python code and shell scipt code via `!`; but once you ask it to run Python code, `ipython` hands it over to Python proper, and you are no longer in `ipython`.

Comment: Thanks for the accept, but my original answer was not really correct. Please review the updated answer.